# Gamemap Border Calculation

Tags: php, arrays, calculator

at the Moment i work on a little Game with an Map.
All will work, but something is unclear.

as you can see here that what i have and want again:
https://picul.de/view/HsY

At the moment my Code looks like this:

```
function calcTile ($x, $y, $tilemin, $tilemax,$atilemin, $atilemax){

//ActualTile 
$m  = calcNoise($x, $y);

//Above Tiles
$tl = calcNoise($x-1, $y-1);
$t  = calcNoise($x, $y-1);
$tr = calcNoise($x+1, $y-1);

//Right Tile
$r  = calcNoise($x+1, $y);

//Below Tiles
$br = calcNoise($x+1, $y+1);
$b  = calcNoise($x, $y+1);
$bl = calcNoise($x-1, $y+1);

//Left Tiles
$l  = calcNoise($x-1, $y);

    if(
        $t >= $tilemin && $t <= $tilemax &&
        $r >= $tilemin && $r <= $tilemax &&
        $b >= $tilemin && $b <= $tilemax &&
        $l >= $tilemin && $l <= $tilemax 
    ){

        $field = 50;

    } else 

//Vertical
    if(
        $t >= $atilemin && $t <= $atilemax &&
        $r >= $tilemin && $r <= $tilemax &&
        $b >= $atilemin && $b <= $atilemax &&
        $l >= $tilemin && $l <= $tilemax
    ){

        $field = 45;

    } else  

//Horizontal
    if(
        $t >= $tilemin && $t <= $tilemax &&
        $r >= $atilemin && $r <= $atilemax &&
        $b >= $tilemin && $b <= $tilemax &&
        $l >= $atilemin && $l <= $atilemax
    ){

        $field = 46;

    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So my new Idea is to Show with Patterns like This:

```
$array = array(
        2 => array(
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '0', '0'

        ), 

        3 => array( '1', '1', '0',
                    '1', '1', '0',
                    '0', '0', '0'
        ),

        4 => array( '0', '0', '0',
                    '1', '1', '0',
                    '1', '1', '0'
        )       
    );

$key = array_search(array('0', '1', '1',
                    '0', '1', '1',
                    '0', '0', '0'), $array);  // $key = 2;
echo $key."<br><br>";
```

This will be work.

But my Problem is, it would be Possible that there are 2 or more Patterns for the same Tile..

My idea was to array the array also

```
array(
        2 => array( array(
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '0', '0'
             ), array(
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '1', '1',
                '0', '0', '1'
             )
        )
```

But the Problem now is that i can't find something cause the array_search want the Array number:

$key = array_search(array('0', '1', '1',
                    '0', '1', '1',
                    '0', '0', '0'), $array[2]);

but how i can solve this Problem? How i can let them know this Number?

This are the Numbers at the Moment:
https://picul.de/view/Hs-

1-50 the other one are test's

Or another Question:
Is there a better Way to "Calculate" the Border / Corner etc?

Greetings
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the array like this:

```
$tiles = [
    1 => [
        '0', '1', '1',
        '0', '1', '1',
        '0', '0', '0'
    ],
    2 => [
        '1', '1', '0',
        '1', '1', '0',
        '0', '0', '0'
    ],
    42 => [
        '0', '0', '0',
        '1', '1', '0',
        '1', '1', '0'
    ]
];

$search_tile = [
    '0', '1', '1',
    '0', '1', '1',
    '0', '0', '0'
];

$found_key = false;

foreach ($tiles as $key => $value) {
    // compare both arrays in some way
    if (implode('', $tile) == implode('', $search_tile)) {
        $found_key = $key;
    }
}
```

... but a loop is not necessary in this case if you define a data structure for the game map. that way you can also define various tiles that have the exact same pattern without confusing them at any point.

```
// these are the available tiles

$tiles = [
    1 => [
        '0', '1', '1',
        '0', '1', '1',
        '0', '0', '0'
    ],
    2 => [
        '1', '1', '0',
        '1', '1', '0',
        '0', '0', '0'
    ],
    12 => [
        '0', '0', '0',
        '1', '1', '0',
        '1', '1', '0'
    ]
];



// this is a game map of 3x2 fields, with a tile mapped to each field.

$map = [
    [ /* field A0 */
        'tile' => 1,
        'other_property' => 'x'
    ],
    [ /* field A1 */
        'tile' => 12,
        'other_property' => 'y'
    ],
    [ /* field A2 */
        'tile' => 2,
        'other_property' => 'z'
    ],
    [ /* field B0 */
        'tile' => 1,
        'other_property' => 'x'
    ],
    [ /* field B1 */
        'tile' => 1,
        'other_property' => 'a'
    ],
    [ /* field B2 */
        'tile' => 12,
        'other_property' => 'b'
    ],
];



// this function returns tile number belonging to the field at X/Y

function get_tile($x, $y, $map, $map_width) {
    $index = $y * $map_width + $x;
    return $map[$index]['tile'];
}


// get the bottom right field's tile number

$tile_index = get_tile( 2, 1, $map, 3 );


// get the tile array from $tiles

$current_tile = $tiles[ $tile_index ];
```